# How to change background color of solution explorer tab in Productivity Power Tools?

Tags: visual-studio, productivity-power-tools

I have docked the solution explorer window as a tabbed document solution explorer, and I am changing the background colors of all file types such as: (.html, .js, .css, and so on) using Productivity Power Tools.

Is there a possibility to change the background color of the solution Explorer Tab in the Custom Document Well?

[image]

> P.S: my Visual Studio is VS2015 Community Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My installed VS2015 version is Professional but this should still work:

**Enable color coding by regex**

Tools-> Options -> Productivity Power Tools -> Custom Document Well -> General: In Group Box "Tab Appearance" switch on `Color tabs by regular expressions`

**Color coding for solution explorer**

Tools-> Options -> Productivity Power Tools -> Custom Document Well -> Color Coding: On the bottom, type in a new `Reg. Ex` with value `Solution Explorer` and pick your wanted color.